# Variable Options without Variables?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    clBoxActive = true;
    clBoxTrigger = "cl-trigger";
    clBoxTriggerType = "#";
    clBoxClass = "overlay-box";
    clEffectIn = "fade";
    clEffectOut = "fade";
    clOnLoad = false;
    clAllowExit = true;
</script>
```

This is what i currently have. Its options to do a lightbox like script where you click on the trigger, and it opens:

```
<div class="overlay-box" style="display:none;">
    <div class="ol-wrapper">
        <div class="ol-box-content">
            This is the overlay box content.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ol-box-bg">&nbsp;</div> 
</div>
```

ol-box-bg is the background which the jquery pulls the height and width of the browser, and set the css to the box, and the rest is in style.css which it says position: absolute; and opacity, and other stuff to just style it to make it black with see through...

ol-box-content is the content box, its got a wrapper to allow it to center, but otherwise its got similar properties in the style.css as the ol-box-bg..

My question is... Im trying to make it a little more dynamic where i can allow multiple lightbox triggers that open different boxes to overlay the pages content. However i came across the problem of, the variables can only be set one time, and i have no clue where to go from here..

I notice that some people do stuff like:

```
optionName: optionvalue
```

but im not sure what it is, or how its used..

Comment: PS sorry if this has already been answered... I couldnt find it anywhere

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  I don't see any code that comes close to creating a light-box.  Maybe you want to create your own jQuery plugin?  It's not that hard.  Basically, if you can write a working script in JavaScript/jQuery, it doesn't take much to add some default options and wrap it in the correct format to be a self-contained plugin.

Comment: Ok so options.. I know some options on some plugins do an array looking thing thats like: option: optionValue.. Whats this? How do I write it, use it.. etc?

Comment: Again, it sounds like you want to write a lightbox plugin.  Yes, you would pass options into it in the way you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a good option to create a plugin.

Which would look something like:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        clBox: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                clBoxActive: true,
                clBoxTrigger: 'cl-trigger',
                clBoxTriggerType: '#',
                clEffectIn: 'fade'
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var obj = $(this);

                // do stuff with matching elements
                obj.click(function() {
                    // e.g. open lightbox
                });

                // to access an option simply use option.name
                console.log(options.clBoxTrigger);             
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You can now use your plugin with either the default options or with custom options.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // with default options
  $('.elements1').clBox();

  // with custom options
  $('.elements2').clBox({clBoxActive: false, clEffectIn: 'slide'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much PeeHaa and Sparky! You guys are awesome! I also got some other ideas from my bud, so I have plenty enough info to do exactly what im looking for! Thanks again!